# How do I change the color of the timepicker in my Android app?

Tags: java, android, native, timepicker

As you can see from the image below, I'm using the time picker in my app.
I need to change the color but don't know how...
Thanks for the help.

[image]

Comment: As far as I know these colors are changed with the themes primary- and secondary colors. So it fits to the rest of your app. If you want to customize it another way you have to create a new style with timepicker as a parent and define your own colors

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27873131/android-timepickerdialog-material-design-color

Comment: @David I changed the primary / secondary colors and it had no effect.

Comment: Thanks @ShinilMS this is what I was looking for.

Comment: @CodeMonkey you can find the solution here: http://www.materialdoc.com/time-pickers/

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved from xml (5.0+ only)

v21/themes.xml

```
<style name="Theme"
       parent="MyTheme.Base">

    <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/Theme.Dialog</item> <!-- TimePicker dialog -->
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/Theme.Dialog</item> <!-- Alert dialog -->

</style>

<style name="Theme.Dialog"
       parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog">

    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/...</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/...</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/...</item>

</style>
```

Edit
Please note that as of Android Support Library 22.1.0 there is a new AppCompatDialog available! http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="TimePicker" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/secondary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="android:buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/DatePickerTheme.ButtonBarButtonStyle</item>
        <item name="android:buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/DatePickerTheme.ButtonBarButtonStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DatePickerTheme.ButtonBarButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

The first one is colorAccent, the second is colorControlActivated and the last one does not belong to the timepicker, it belongs to dialog so you should apply the an style similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50771830/change-the-text-color-of-one-of-the-buttons-in-datepickerdialog)