# Hide the hour hand from the clock and just have the circle Android Time Dialog

Tags: java, android, xml, mobile

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUawU.jpg

How would you achieve this in android via an xml layout? I just need a layout but with this exact view. But problem is with the TimePicker I cannot seem to figure out a way to hide the line pointing to the hour. By default it looks likes this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/x45Zn.jpg) and I am trying to achieve the image above. I have been searching for this answer for quite sometime now any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try to look at this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27873131/android-timepickerdialog-material-design-color

Comment: Hey zero thank you for responding sadly that doesn't help. Unless you know of a way to call the line that leads up to the hour number and hide the line only. Or even make it transparent. But I do need the time colored like the image just don't need the line leading up to the hour is all.

Comment: so you just want to hide the Hand of the clock.. try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24449723/is-it-possible-to-change-the-style-of-an-android-l-timepickerdialog

Comment: Hey zero I just looked at that link and that doesn't specify anything about how to hide the hand. It just  theming the clock which is sort of what I need but I do not know what parameter I would change in order to hide the clock hand.